# How to control the number of Units showing in central pane?

Tags: ide, delphi-10.4-sydney, delphi-units

Recently moved to Delphi 10.4 and I get far too many Units showing in the central pane of the IDE. (It didn't happen with XE.)

[image: top bar of central pane]

My main project group has up to 15 programs in it.

[image: list of programs in Group]

I can remove each unit manually from view in the central pane, but if I close the Project Group they all come back again!

Is there a setting I can use so a large Project Group only opens with 1 Mainform of the selected Project initially showing (as I had in Delphi XE)?

(The reason for multiple projects is they share lots of common features and form a toolbox suite.)

Grateful for advice.

Comment: What do you have configured as your autosave options?

Comment: Save files when compiling or running. (I also have Autorecover checked, 10 minutes.)

Comment: Do you have "Save project desktop when closing" unchecked?

Comment: yes,  I do. I had it checked a couple of weeks ago and unchecked it hoping that'd help. It didn't..

Comment: I've just tried a new Project Group with only 3 of the original programs in it. (There were 18 in the one I reported above.) With 3, there's no problem, just one program's main form Unit is showing. I guess there is some limit I exceeded at 18.....